# Including resources outside context root with JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm currently upgrading an application from JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3 to JSF 2 and Richfaces 4.

I'm having issues getting my application to include stylesheets using JSF2's new [h:outputStylesheet](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html) component

Here is my old code:

```
<a4j:loadStyle src="resource:///com/testing/test/html/css/style.xcss" />
```

And here is what I have for my new code (Not working):

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="resource:///com/testing/test/html/css/" name="style.xcss" />
```

I've tried various variations but none have worked.
I get a message saying RES_NOT_FOUND when using firebugs css tab.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="resource:///com/testing/test/html/css/" name="style.xcss" />
```

will not work for one reason - the library name is not the location of the resource, rather it is used to determine the location of the resource.

The manner in which the JSF runtime serves resources is detailed in the JSF 2.0 specification in chapter 2 titled "Request Processing Lifecyle". Resource handling is performed outside the confines of the usual Execute and Render lifecyle of JSF (that is used to service View requests). At runtime, a `ResourceHandler` associated with the `Application` is responsible for serving Resource requests.

The `ResourceHandler` uses a path based approach for looking up requests. The default implementation allows for resources to be placed in two locations:

- In the Web-Application Root. Resources with identifier  have to be placed in the `/resources` directory under the Web Application root, as `/resources/<resourceIdentifier>`.
- In the Classpath. Resources with identifier  must be present in the Classpath under the `META-INF/resources` directory, again as `META-INF/resources/<resourceIdentifier>`. In a web application, I've noticed that the directory should be the `Web Application Root/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources` directory or a `META-INF/resources` directory under one of the directories in the parent classloader(s), or even in a JAR present in the Classpath. Apparently, the last option is the one undertaken by JSF 2 libraries/frameworks like PrimeFaces.

The JSF specification also specifies how the `<resourceIdentifier>` may consist of locales, library versions and resource versions, apart from the resource name itself. This is dealt with in a concise manner, in the [`ResourceHandler` API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html):

> Packaging Resources
>
> ResourceHandler defines a path based packaging convention for
>   resources. The default implementation of ResourceHandler must support
>   packaging resources in the classpath or in the web application root.
>   See section JSF.2.6.1 of the spec prose document linked in the
>   overview summary for the normative specification of packaging
>   resources.
>
> Briefly, The default implementation must support packaging resources
>   in the web application root under the path
>
> ```
> resources/<resourceIdentifier>
> ```
>
> relative to the web app root.
>
> For the default implementation, resources packaged in the classpath
>   must reside under the JAR entry name
>
> ```
> META-INF/resources/<resourceIdentifier>
> ```
>
> consists of several segments, specified as
>   follows.
>
> ```
> [localePrefix/][libraryName/][libraryVersion/]resourceName[/resourceVersion]
> ```
>
> None of the segments in the resourceIdentifier may be relative paths,
>   such as ‘../otherLibraryName’. The implementation is not required to
>   support the libraryVersion and resourceVersion segments for the JAR
>   packaging case.
>
> Note that resourceName is the only required segment.

Going by the above, the following may work:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="com/testing/test/html/css" name="style.xcss" />
```

provided that the stylesheet `style.xcss` is present in the directory structure `com/testing/test/html/css` located in either of the two areas mentioned above. Going by your need to place it outside the context root, the only possible option would be `Web Application Root/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources` or any of the other suitable directory/JAR in the classpath (containing a `META-INF/resources` directory. This is of course, assuming that RichFaces does not provide it's own implementation of a `ResourceHandler`; if it does provide one, you should be looking at how it extends the default implementation to allow for resources to be placed elsewhere.

---

In Mojarra, the `com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl` class extends the `ResourceHandler` class. `ResourceHanderImpl` uses the `com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager` class for finding resources. In turn, the `ResourceManager` delegates the loading of resources to the `com.sun.faces.application.resource.WebappResourceHelper` and `com.sun.faces.application.resource.ClasspathResourceHelper` classes. As their names imply, the former is responsible for looking up resources in the Web Application root, while the former is responsible for loading resources from the classpath. Going through these classes, one would find that failed attempts to load libraries get logged in the server's log; the `RES_NOT_FOUND` value is not generated by these classes, rather it is due to the renderer responsible for generating the page output.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Vineet. I'll look into the suggestions you made and more than likely be coming back to accept this as the answer :)

Comment: I've reorganisied the application to store css/js/images all under the resources folder in the webapp now, thanks Vineet.

Comment: Note: This answer is wrong in one aspect: slash (/) characters in a libraryName are illegal as per the JSF spec: http://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces-spec-public/lists/jsr344-experts/archive/2012-03/message/26

Comment: @Péter Varga, I haven't stated that slashes are allowed in library names; slashes are in fact allowed for whole resource identifiers.