# Using CSS in composite components in a JAR

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have created a composite component in JSF2. I works great.

I would like to create it as JAR for future use.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.java-javafx.com/2011_02_01_archive.html).

However, when it comes to CSS the browser refers to the location relatively to the project that uses the jar and not to the Jar location!

I defined it like this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="component.css" target="head" />
```

and I get this exception: `GET http://localhost:8080/MY_APPLICATION/resources/component.css 404 (Not Found)`

It's looking for it relatively to the projects,  and not to the Jar project!

How can I make it relative to the JAR project?

**EDITED**

The JAR tree is:

```
META-INF
 --resource
   -- components
      myComp.xhtml
      components.css
   -- img
   -- scripts 
 --components.taglib.xml
 --faces.config.xml
```

The war is a regular dynamic project:

```
WEB-INF
--lib
  myJar.jar
-- web.xml
-- faces-config.xml
testComp.xhtml
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of your JAR file, and the WAR file that contains it? I have a feeling that either the JAR file doesn't contain the CSS stylesheet, or something else is amiss. Also, consider reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846284/including-resources-outside-context-root-with-jsf2/6847985#6847985) posted a few hours back. I hope it will help you understand how resources are located at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JAR directory structure should be:

```
META-INF
 --resources
   -- components
        myComp.xhtml
   -- css                <-- The library defined in the stylesheet
        components.css   <-- A stylesheet resource in the library
   -- img
   -- scripts 
 --components.taglib.xml
 --faces.config.xml
```

Since, you are specifying the library name as `css` in the `h:outputStylesheet` tag with the resource name as `component.css`, the file should be present in a directory named `css` located in `META-INF/resources` directory of the JAR file.

Also, consider using a library name that is not bound to conflict with other names, if you intend to allow other developers to use your JAR.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the resource needs to be located in the same directory as the composite component. Have you tried to put the css in the same library?

Comment: I put it in the same directory but it didn't help:(